# jquery DragAndDrop setup does not work properly

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have built a TreeView which renders as follows (only the first li is shown here, the rest is similar):

```
<li class="t-item cas ui-droppable ui-draggable" data-id="930" data-typesuffix="CAS">
<div class="t-top"><span class="t-icon t-minus"></span><span class="t-in"><img alt="(C)" class="t-image" src="#">cabine</span>
    <input
    class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="930CAS">
</div>
<ul class="t-group" style="">
    <li class="t-item cas ui-droppable ui-draggable" data-id="2563" data-typesuffix="CAS">
        <div class="t-top"><span class="t-icon t-plus"></span><span class="t-in"><img alt="(C)" class="t-image" src="#">porte conducteur</span>
            <input
            class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="2563CAS">
        </div>
        <ul class="t-group" style="display:none">
            <li class="t-item csm ui-draggable" data-id="20280" data-typesuffix="CSM">
                <div class="t-top"><span class="t-in"><img alt="(M)" class="t-image" src="#">Carnet de km , 1 pces</span>
                    <input
                    class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="{&quot;ID_CSM&quot;:20280,&quot;IDMAT_CSM&quot;:66,&quot;IDCAS_CSM&quot;:2563,&quot;CANTITEFIXE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;REMARQUES_CSM&quot;:null,&quot;NOORDRE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;materiel&quot;:{&quot;id_MAT&quot;:66,&quot;DEN_MAT&quot;:&quot;Carnet de km&quot;,&quot;DEN_UME&quot;:&quot;pces&quot;}}">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="t-item t-last csm ui-draggable" data-id="20281" data-typesuffix="CSM">
                <div class="t-bot"><span class="t-in"><img alt="(M)" class="t-image" src="#">Gilet sécurité , 1 pces</span>
                    <input
                    class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="{&quot;ID_CSM&quot;:20281,&quot;IDMAT_CSM&quot;:694,&quot;IDCAS_CSM&quot;:2563,&quot;CANTITEFIXE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;REMARQUES_CSM&quot;:null,&quot;NOORDRE_CSM&quot;:2,&quot;materiel&quot;:{&quot;id_MAT&quot;:694,&quot;DEN_MAT&quot;:&quot;Gilet sécurité&quot;,&quot;DEN_UME&quot;:&quot;pces&quot;}}">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="t-item cas ui-droppable ui-draggable" data-id="2565" data-typesuffix="CAS">
        <div class="t-mid"><span class="t-icon t-minus"></span><span class="t-in"><img alt="(C)" class="t-image" src="#">console</span>
            <input
            class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="2565CAS">
        </div>
        <ul class="t-group" style="">
            <li class="t-item t-last csm ui-draggable" data-id="20315" data-typesuffix="CSM">
                <div class="t-top t-bot"><span class="t-in"><img alt="(M)" class="t-image" src="#">Télécomande porte , 1 pces</span>
                    <input
                    class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="{&quot;ID_CSM&quot;:20315,&quot;IDMAT_CSM&quot;:1620,&quot;IDCAS_CSM&quot;:2565,&quot;CANTITEFIXE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;REMARQUES_CSM&quot;:null,&quot;NOORDRE_CSM&quot;:2,&quot;materiel&quot;:{&quot;id_MAT&quot;:1620,&quot;DEN_MAT&quot;:&quot;Télécomande porte&quot;,&quot;DEN_UME&quot;:&quot;pces&quot;}}">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="t-item cas ui-droppable ui-draggable" data-id="2566" data-typesuffix="CAS">
        <div class="t-mid"><span class="t-icon t-plus"></span><span class="t-in"><img alt="(C)" class="t-image" src="#">boite à gants</span>
            <input
            class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="2566CAS">
        </div>
        <ul class="t-group" style="display:none">
            <li class="t-item t-last csm ui-draggable" data-id="20320" data-typesuffix="CSM">
                <div class="t-top t-bot"><span class="t-in"><img alt="(M)" class="t-image" src="#">Trousseau divers clés boule  , 1 pces</span>
                    <input
                    class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="{&quot;ID_CSM&quot;:20320,&quot;IDMAT_CSM&quot;:1329,&quot;IDCAS_CSM&quot;:2566,&quot;CANTITEFIXE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;REMARQUES_CSM&quot;:null,&quot;NOORDRE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;materiel&quot;:{&quot;id_MAT&quot;:1329,&quot;DEN_MAT&quot;:&quot;Trousseau divers clés boule &quot;,&quot;DEN_UME&quot;:&quot;pces&quot;}}">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="t-item cas ui-droppable ui-draggable" data-id="2567" data-typesuffix="CAS">
        <div class="t-mid"><span class="t-icon t-plus"></span><span class="t-in"><img alt="(C)" class="t-image" src="#">porte passagers</span>
            <input
            class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="2567CAS">
        </div>
        <ul class="t-group" style="display:none">
            <li class="t-item t-last csm ui-draggable" data-id="20324" data-typesuffix="CSM">
                <div class="t-top t-bot"><span class="t-in"><img alt="(M)" class="t-image" src="#">Gilet sécurité , 2 pces</span>
                    <input
                    class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="{&quot;ID_CSM&quot;:20324,&quot;IDMAT_CSM&quot;:694,&quot;IDCAS_CSM&quot;:2567,&quot;CANTITEFIXE_CSM&quot;:2,&quot;REMARQUES_CSM&quot;:null,&quot;NOORDRE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;materiel&quot;:{&quot;id_MAT&quot;:694,&quot;DEN_MAT&quot;:&quot;Gilet sécurité&quot;,&quot;DEN_UME&quot;:&quot;pces&quot;}}">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="t-item t-last csm ui-draggable" data-id="20314" data-typesuffix="CSM">
        <div class="t-bot"><span class="t-in"><img alt="(M)" class="t-image" src="#">Carte essence , 1 pces</span>
            <input
            class="t-input" name="itemValue" type="hidden" value="{&quot;ID_CSM&quot;:20314,&quot;IDMAT_CSM&quot;:1619,&quot;IDCAS_CSM&quot;:930,&quot;CANTITEFIXE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;REMARQUES_CSM&quot;:null,&quot;NOORDRE_CSM&quot;:1,&quot;materiel&quot;:{&quot;id_MAT&quot;:1619,&quot;DEN_MAT&quot;:&quot;Carte essence&quot;,&quot;DEN_UME&quot;:&quot;pces&quot;}}">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In javascript I have the following setup for drag and drop:

```
$('#stockTreeView').on('stockLoad', function () {
    $('.cas').droppable(
        {
            accept: '.materiel',
            drop: function (event, ui) {

                var addRequest =
                {
                    ID_MAT: $('#Materiel').data('tGrid').dataItem($(ui.draggable).closest('tr')).ID_MAT,
                    ID_CAS: $(this).closest("li").data('id')
                };
                console.log(addRequest);
                addMaterielWindowManager.LoadWindowContent('Stock/AddMateriel', addRequest, 'Ajouter materiel');
            }
        }
    ).droppable(
        {
            accept: '.cas',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var changeParentRequest =
                {
                    ID_CAS: $(ui.draggable).parent().data('id'),
                    IDCASPARENT_CAS: $(this).parent().data('id')
                };
                console.log(changeParentRequest);
                $.post(
                    GetURL('Stock/UpdateCasierParent'),
                    changeParentRequest,
                    loadTreeView
                );
            }
        }
    ).droppable(
        {
            accept: '.csm',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var changeParentRequest =
                {
                    ID_CSM: $(ui.draggable).data('id'),
                    IDCAS_CSM: $(this).data('id')
                };
                console.log(changeParentRequest);
                $.post(
                    GetURL('Stock/UpdateCasierMateriel'),
                    changeParentRequest,
                    loadTreeView
                );
            }
        }
    );

    $('.cas, .csm').draggable(
        {
            helper: 'clone',
            appendTo: 'body',
            revert: 'invalid'
        }
    );

});
```

The problem which i need help with is this: how can I make my selector(s) more specific in order for me to be able to drag to each '.cas' node. In my current situation, whenever i drag anything, it gets appended to the top level '.cas' element in the list, e.g. for every li in the child ul for the li with the data-id = 930, i get 930 as the data-id, not the data-id value of the current node.

The jquery plugin i use is jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js.

Thanks in advance,
Silviu

L.E. : as you can see, i have tried multiple ways for getting the needed id, but all of them point to the top-level '.cas' li element.

L.L.E: I also have to mention that the classes do not add any styling to the elements, they are just there in order to serve as selectors.

Comment: Nothing? I still am trying to fix this, and still stuck...so maybe someone will take another look at this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...the ordeal is over, dear folks!!! When building the tree, I have changed the positioning of the `class`, `data-id` and `data-typesuffix` HTML attributes, so that they are now placed in the `<span class="t-in">` element, rather then in its parent, the `<li>` element.

In the js part, all I need is:

```
accept: '.cas',
drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var changeParentRequest =
                    {
                        ID_CAS: $(ui.draggable).data('id'),
                        IDCASPARENT_CAS: $(this).data('id')
                    };
                    $.postAntiForgery(
                        GetURL('Stock/UpdateCasierParent'),
                        changeParentRequest,
                        loadTreeView
                    );
                }
```

The same goes for the .csm and .material classes. Good for me, I say :)

Cheers and happy coding, ppl.

Silviu